# How to Implement a Restart Button in a Number Guessing Game using JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple number guessing game in JavaScript, and I'm trying to implement a restart button to reset the game to its initial state. I have already created the game logic and user interface using HTML and JavaScript DOM manipulation.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
const secretNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 21);

let score = 20;

document.querySelector('.check').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const guess = Number(document.querySelector('.guess').value);

    // When there is no input
    if (!guess) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '❌ No Number';

        // When player win
    } else if (guess === secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = '  Correct Number ! ';
        document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#60b347';document.querySelector('.number'),style.width = '30rem'
        document.querySelector('.number').textContent = secretNumber;


    }
    // When guess to high
    else if (guess > secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' Too High!';
        score--;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
    }

    
    // guess too low - STUDY ONLY Line 55 annd 56
    else if (guess < secretNumber) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' Too Low!';
        score--;
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
    }

    // this when you lost
    if (score === 0) {
        document.querySelector('.message').textContent = ' You Lost The Game!';

        // STUDY THIS LINE
        document.querySelector('.score').textContent = 0;

    }
});
```

I've added a restart button to the HTML file,

Answer (score 0):

First there seems to be a typo here if you're not aware :

```
document.querySelector('.number'),style.width = '30rem'
```

Should be :

```
document.querySelector('.number').style.width = '30rem'
```

For the reset function, if I understand correctly you might want to reset UI elements and scores to their initial state.
So you could do something like this, without more details as what behavior you are expecting :

```js
const resetGame = () => {
  // Reset score and secretNumber
  score = // reset here to whatever you want
  secretNumber = // reset here to whatever you want

    // reset UI elements
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Start guessing...';
  document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
  document.querySelector('.number').textContent = '?';
  document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#222';
  document.querySelector('.number').style.width = '15rem';
  document.querySelector('.guess').value = ''; // clear input field
};

// add event listener to reset button
document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', resetGame);
```